# Assign default priority cookie to captured tasks

Tags: org-mode

I looking for a way to explicitly add priority cookies to tasks created via org-capture with default the cookie that represents `org-priority-default`. This is to avoid the situation that some tasks rely on default priority that may change over time, rather than the one attached at the moment of their creation.

This should be possible to be achieved using `‘%(EXP)’` in `org-capture-templates`, by taking `org-priority-default` and converting it to cookie representation.

How the `org-capture-templates` should look to work like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think adding this to your init file

```
(defun prio ()
   (format "[#%c]" org-default-priority))
```

and then using

```
...
* %(prio) TODO
...
```

in your capture template should do the trick. E.g.

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
  '("s" "Shopping" entry
      (file+headline "~/lib/org/shopping.org" "Shopping")
 "* %(prio) TODO %?
  %U"
   :prepend t))
```